# How to increment nvarchar value by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-insert

I have a table to archive changes to user information, in which the primary key is a userid + the incremental number of the next change to the specific user's information. i.e the first key for user 1234 is 1234+000, and the subsequent change to this user's information would appear in the archive table (the next row for user 1234) as 1234+001.

So I have the table dbo.userchanges already with the following information for user 1234:

```
userkey, userid, usercntxt, usergroup
1234+000, 1234, lms, _default
1234+001, 1234, lms, _general_use
```

If it is found that the user's userctxt changes to 'ils' then the next row would be:

```
1234+002, 1234, ils, _general_use
```

My question is, how can I use TSQL to insert row 1234+002 for this user, or in general how can I insert 1234+00n+1 if the table already has 1234+00n?

Comment: Oh... good old "intelligent codes". They were in vogue in the 80s. Honestly I would recommend to steer clear of this design. It's very rigid and ends up adding a lot of low level logic needlessly to you business logic. They just make things complicated. Use a composite key such as (user, datetime) or similar instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is consistently made of 8 characters, with the 3 digits at the end that you want to increment, then you can do:

```
left(userkey, 5) + format(convert(int, right(userkey, 3)) + 1, '00#')
```

The idea is to extract the last 3 characters, convert to a number, increment and then format back to three digits with possible leading zeros.

If you wanted an `insert` query that generates the user key by "incrementing" its last known key, then:

```
insert into userchanges (userkey, userid, usercntxt, usergroup)
select coalesce(k.userkey, v.userid + '#000'), v.*
from (values (@userid, @usercntxt, @usergroup)) as v(userkey, userid, usercntxt, usergroup)
outer apply (
    select top (1) left(userkey, 5) + format(convert(int, right(userkey, 3)) + 1, '00#') userkey
    from userchanges u
    where u.userid = v.userid
    order by u.userkey desc
) k
```

If the user has no row in the table yet, a new key is generated, starting at index `000`.